# What is the difference between passing nothing and passing null to View?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

As I am a newbie in ASP.NET MVC, my question might be too basic. I have not explored the details yet but I urgently want to know the answer of the following question.

What is the difference between passing nothing and passing null to View?

### Passing nothing:

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

### Passing null:

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        Movie m = null;
        return View(m);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the view's point-of-view there's no difference. In fact, first method is just an overload for second, passing `null`.

Comment: Sorry. What is the difference between `return View(new Movie());` and `return View();` in `[HttpGet] Create` action method?

Comment: The former returns a view over a newly created object, the latter returns a view over nothing.

Comment: I posted a question about [my comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57313438/5482465). If you have any other opinion, please kindly let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The 1st will call parameterless `View()` [method/constructor], the 2nd will attempt to find a [method/constructor] `View(...)` defined with one parameter that is the closest match to the object you are passing - it may fail completely as `null` has no type as such and therefore can not be matched exactly, so if you have more than one method `View(...)` defined with one parameter, then it will cause an error.

Comment: The question was asked in a specific context which implies knowledge of `Controller` class, which has well-defined methods with name `View`.

Comment: @SergRogovtsev I always thought if such a question was asked that implies absence or inadequate knowledge of the basics - this is why I explained the concept. It is always better to know the concept (that can be extended and reused) instead of just knowing the particular method.

Comment: It seems to me that there's a confusion between `View` method, which you are explaning, and `View` concept in MVC, which the question was about. As far as I can see, the question is about framework behavior ("what will be passed"), not c# overload resolution.

Comment: @SergRogovtsev And how is the `View` concept in MVC implemented? Is it **NOT** a constructor/method?

Comment: In short, it is not. In short, it is *something* to be consumed by `ViewEngine` and produce some kind of result.