# Why don't we need to return View(new Person()) in HttpGet Create?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I noticed almost all code I found just `return View();` in `[HttpGet] Create` action method. I wonder why don't we need to `return View(new Person())` for example?

Comment: Maybe that view doesn't need a model?

Comment: @Amy: The view has `@model Person` at the top.

Comment: That does not indicate that the view needs a model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the default constructs you use in a razor view template (like `Html.EditorFor`, `Html.LabelFor`, etc) work when the model is null. They can access the meta data of the class type of the model for tasks like displaying the label or deciding on the required format of the value. And they just use an empty value (empty string, 0, false) for the value when the model instance is null.

So, the code you see (View called without model instance) will only run into trouble if there is code in the view template that manually attempts to access the model instance without checking whether it is null.

Still, in my opinion it is best practice to pass a new instance of the Model or ViewModel type when calling a view to create a new object. This way, default values set in the constructor of the Model or ViewModel or values set in the controller action before will not be lost and used in the view. Also, there will not be a problem when someone modifying the view template decides to access the model instance without null checks.

Comment: I agree with this. Best to pass a model in and that way you can set defaults if needed.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what code you're looking at, but if I'm returning a view that requires a viewmodel, I will pretty much always include the viewmodel object when I call the view.

```
    public ActionResult ViewTime(int id, DateTime? from, DateTime? to)
    {
        var viewTimeModel = _repository.ViewTime_Read(User, from, to, id);
        return View(viewTimeModel);
    }
```

It's possible that the view has some dynamic controls, like grids, etc in it that are responsible for getting their own data, perhaps via javascript calls to the controller methods for json. In that case, the view is pretty much a "dumb shell" and the controls on it are doing the heavy lifting.